# Referencing to MVC Core RemoteAttribute in class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reference, asp.net-core-mvc

In my solution I have a few projects, one is my MVC Core project and another is a class library containing the MVC models. I've been trying to add a **Remote attribute** to one of my model-properties, which can be seen below.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required"), 
        StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1, 
        ErrorMessage = "Username needs to be between 1 and 20 characters"), 
        RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Username can only contain letters and numbers")]
    [Remote(action: "IsUsernameAvailable", controller: "Account")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the Remote part gets me the error

> The type or namespace name 'Remote' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I'm fairly certain this problem occurs due to having the check within my non-MVC project in my class library, but this should obviously still work.

I first added the MVC nuget to my class library, which solved the "could not be found" error I was getting in my model, however that caused issue in my MVC Core view, as my MVC project references my class library. I therefore uninstalled the MVC nuget to replace it with MVC Core, but doing this doesn't solve the model "could not be found" error, even though packages.config contains "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core".

I googled to find that the RemoteAttribute class is located within the [MVC.ViewFeautures](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c27b07ef3f8b07dfe1d1de38a8d7bf2d6a9298f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/RemoteAttribute.cs) folder, not within the MVC Core code. My MVC Core project uses the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" nuget, which contains both MVC and MVC Core, so installing this should fix the issue, but when doing so I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.           0

I've tried to add references in the project, but haven't found any available MVC references. I've also tried adding usings to the model class but haven't helped either. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: seems that you need to reference the `ViewFeatures` package to both projects, but first you need to make sure both of them are Core Projects

Comment: Didn't even know that ViewFeautures was a installable nuget package, installing the same version used in my MVC Core project solved my issue, thank you very much!